# Proving that $2xy'=4x^{2}+3y^{2}$ has no real solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation above is a Ricatti equation. I'm not given any particular solution to it. I'm actually asked to solve it. I tried graphing the direction field to get an idea on the behavior of the curve with no result.

However, it is true that this equation has no real solution. To solve it we need to use Bessel equations (I'm still being introduced to second order differential equations).

How can we prove that $2xy'=4x^{2}+3y^{2}$ has no real solution? Can we use the existence and unicity theorem?

Also, it is possible to prove it without using Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: This equation has plenty of real solutions!

Comment: Is it possibe to prove that it has real solutions? Is there any simple way to solve it?

Comment: Yes it is.  I'll show how in my answer--give me a few minutes.  Cheers!

Comment: I gave a brief answer which deals with the case $x \ne 0$; not sure if this is what you're looking for; hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation

$2xy' = 4x^2 + 3y^2 \tag 1$

has a local real solution through any $(x_0, y_0)$, where $y_0 = y(x_0)$, provided
$x_0 \ne 0$; to see this, note that about any $x_0 \ne 0$ there is an open interval
$I = (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$, where $\delta < \vert x_0 \vert$, such that

$x \in I \Longrightarrow x \ne 0; \tag 2$

then on $I$ we may write (1) as

$y' = 2x + \dfrac{3y^2}{2x} = f(x, y); \tag 3$

since $f(x, y)$ is differentiable for $(x, y) \in I \times \Bbb R$, it is both continuous in $x$ and locally Lipschitz continuous in $y$ on $I \times \Bbb R$; this fact is quite well-known and has been discussed more than once on this site.  Since $f(x, y)$ is continuous in $x$ and locally Lipschitz continuous in $y$ on $I \times \Bbb R$, the [Picard-Lindeloef theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) shows that (2) has a unique *real* solution through any $(x_0, y_0) \in I \times \Bbb R$; hence does (1) since $x \ne 0$ on $I$.

I don't know how to show (1)-(2) has unique solutions where $x \ne 0$ without Picard-Lindeloef, which requires $f(x, y)$ to meet the criterion given in the previous paragraph.

On the other hand, and I haven't the time to analyze this in detail at the moment, there may be challenges in trying to extend a solution to/through the $x$-value $x = 0$.  So perhaps that is what is meant by saying there are no real solutions--there may not be on all of $\Bbb R$.

Perhaps someone else can chime in here . . .

Comment: I think you are redefining the function's domain. Does this means that the equation has no solution on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$? Since $f(x,y)$ is not continuous.

Comment: @IchVerloren:   Well, since you didn't specify the domain explicitly, I just assumed and went for local solutions on intervals where $f(x, y)$ *is* defined; I did mention the problem with $x = 0$, but as I said I haven't yet been able to analyze it.  It would not surprise me if there are no solutions if we allow $x = 0$ in the interval over which the equation is taken.   Simply not sure at this point . . .